# Query execution time in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, tools

I know I can use `set timing on` to see how long it took to execute a query after the execution is finished.

But is it possible to see **current** execution duration in Oracle SQL Developer while the query is still running?

SQL Server Management Studio as well as old Query Analyzer have such a feature:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On recent versions you can see a timer in the "Task Progress" view (View->Task Progress). Annoyingly it resets to zero the moment the task finishes! :

[image: progress]

Comment: In German versions it is called Fortschritt - Task

Comment: @bernd - doesn't that mean 'tractor' :)

Comment: On my machine (4.0.2.15, build 15.21) it doesn't reset, but it DOES freeze up, and often.  It's been stuck at 00:32 for the past few minutes, now.  Surely there's some other more robust way to get elapsed time?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I'm using 4.0.0.3 and mine still resets. I'm unlikely to upgrade because for every issue that gets fixed I get bitten by a new one.

Comment: I can see the elapsed time of completed queries in the Statements window.